# Completing the square to show that $4x^2 - 5y^2 + 24y = 16$ is a hyperbola

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, completing-the-square

I was wondering how would I complete the square for this particular hyperbola?$$4x^2 - 5y^2 + 24y = 16$$

I tried this technique but to no avail:
\begin{align*}
4x^2 - 5(y^2 + \frac{24}{5}y) & = 16\\
4x^2 - 5(y + \frac{12}{5})^2 & = 16 + \left(\frac{12}{5}\right)^2\\
4x^2 - 5(y + \frac{12}{5})^2 & = \frac{544}{25}
\end{align*}

Am I doing something wrong here? On my calculator it says that the equation should be a hyperbola.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, don't forget that when you factor out that "-5" to make the "completion of squares" easier, it also has to be factored out of +24y, so the equation becomes

$$4x^2 - 5(y^2 - \frac{24}{5}y ) = 16 $$

(as lab bhattacharjee already has).

You then complete the square by adding the term $\frac{12^2}{5^2}$ within the parentheses.  **However,** since it is *inside* the parentheses, what you have just "added" to the left-hand side of the equation is *really*  $-5 \cdot (\frac{12^2}{5^2})$, so the equation must be sustained by writing

$$4x^2 - 5(y^2 - \frac{24}{5}y  +  [\frac{12^2}{5^2}]) = 16 -5 \cdot (\frac{12^2}{5^2}) ,$$

now making the equation

$$4x^2 - 5(y -\frac{12}{5})^2 = 16 -(\frac{12^2}{5})  =  \frac{16 \cdot 5 - 144}{5} = \frac{-64}{5}  .$$

Putting the equation for this hyperbola in standard form gives us

$$\frac{-5 \cdot 4x^2}{64} - \frac{-5 \cdot 5(y -\frac{12}{5})^2}{64}   = 1 \Rightarrow \frac{25(y -\frac{12}{5})^2}{64} - \frac{20x^2}{64}    = 1.$$

[or, of course, $\frac{(y -\frac{12}{5})^2}{64/25} - \frac{x^2}{64/20}    = 1$]

So this is a "vertical" hyperbola, with its focal axis along the y-axis, since it is the *y-term* that is positive.  (Graphing the original and this standard-form equation confirms that they are identical.)

Answer (score 4):

You have wrongly added $\left(\frac{12}5\right)^2$ in place of subtraction

$(2x)^2-5\{y^2-2\cdot y\cdot \frac{12}5+ (\frac{12}5)^2\}=16- \left(\frac{12}5\right)^2$

or, $(2x)^2-5\left(y- \frac{12}5\right)^2=\frac{256}{25}=\left(\frac{16}5\right)^2$
and so on